# Flutter AutofillHints oneTimeCode doesn't work

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, one-time-password

I want to catch OTP sms code but it doesn't work on IOS.
I need show the code upper of keyboard.

my code block is;

```
TextField(
 controller: controller,
 autofillHints: const <String>[AutofillHints.oneTimeCode],
 keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
 onChanged: onChanged,
),
```

Answer (score 2):

From Flutter docs at https://master-api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/autofillHints.html "Some autofill hints only work with specific keyboardTypes". Try changing the keyboardType. For example:

```
TextField(
 controller: controller,
 autofillHints: const <String>[AutofillHints.oneTimeCode],
 keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
 onChanged: onChanged,
),
```